# Two equal columns with image that crops from the right - CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating a two-column equal width section using that has an image in the left column/section that I want to crop from the right as the screen resizes.

I want to fix the height of the image (on the left), as well as stretching the element (and maintaining background colour) if the text in the text in the right column ends up being higher than the image size.

I have tried 'normal' css as well as flexbox with stretch and flex-grow but I can't get it to work.

I don't know how to get a) the sizing to work properly or b) get it to crop from the side

```
<div class="section">
 <div class="image">
   <img src="http://xxx.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
   text_abc
  </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work:

```
.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: centre;
}

.image {
  background-color: #f9f6ec;
   width: 428px;
   flex-grow: 1;
 }

 .text {
   font-size: 1.25em;
   padding: 31px;
   background-color: #f9f6ec;
   flex-grow: 1;
 }
```

neither does:

```
.section {
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  background-color: #f9f6ec;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.text {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 31px;
  background-color: #f9f6ec;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand from your question, you want something like this:

```css
.section
{
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.image
{
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #f9f6ec;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/image_output/nightlife-q-c-640-480-5.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
}

.text
{
  flex: 1;
   font-size: 1.25em;
   background-color: #f9f6ec;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
 <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="text">
   text_abc
  </div>
</div>
```

You can crop the images as much as you want using `background-size` and `background-position`

Comment: Thanks. I want the section to be full width, but I guess I can take away 'width' there. Also I didn't know about the URL background image as I was calling the image in the html